# BCM43225 wireless card has connectivity problems

Tags: wireless, broadcom, internet-connection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get a Broadcom BCM43225 wireless card working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234047/how-do-i-get-a-broadcom-bcm43225-wireless-card-working)

Yesterday, I installed Ubuntu 12.04 as a dual-boot with Windows 7 64 bit. This is the very first time I've touched a linux system and so any attempt to research my problem on Google returns myriad pages that I don't understand.

My problem is that I immediately had connectivity issues with my wireless. It often drops the connection, and when it is connected, it's pretty slow. The wireless card is a BCM43225.

I tried updating the broadcom sta driver found in the Additional Drivers section, and I found another thread that told me I should download and install:
b43-fwcutter  and
firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
I've done that, but it doesn't seem to have helped.

Please help me get this figured out. PLEASE REMEMBER THAT I AM A LINUX/UBUNTU NOOB, so I likely won't understand any jargon or too-specific terms. However, I do understand the basics of running commands and programs from a terminal, at least as far as it's similar to Windows.

From reading on other threads, I think the following terminal output will be asked for, so here it is:

```
don@ubuntu:~$ rfkill list
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
don@ubuntu:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for don: 
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: b8:70:f4:e5:12:43
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.121 firmware=sb latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 memory:d1830000-d183ffff memory:d1840000-d184ffff memory:d1850000-d18507ff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43225 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 68:a3:c4:44:81:96
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=3.2.0-23-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.12 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:d1900000-d1903fff
don@ubuntu:~$
```

---

Ok, it turns out this is not fixed. After spending some hours in Windows job-hunting, I switched back to Ubuntu, margarita in hand, ready to play with my new OS. And I encountered laaaaaaaaaaaaag. It's been five minutes and Gmail still hasn't loaded - strangely, this page loaded almost instantaneously. Facebook is doing ok. Speedtest.net won't load more than the banner.

I tried disabling the broadcom sta driver that WAS enabled, but that hasn't helped matters any.

So to summarize up to this point:
`b43-fwcutter & firmware-b43-lpphy-installer` have been installed and removed - they didn't fix the problem.
`bcmwl-kernel-source` is installed, but doesn't appear to have fixed the problem.
Additional Drivers lists the Broadband STA driver, which I have tried on and off with the above configurations.

`$ sudo just-work-already -dear_god_please`

Are there any other things I can try?

@Eliah, thanks for the heads-up. I'd never used a forum like this before, and my brain was already melting from all the other new things I have to learn for Ubuntu.

Update: After waiting a while, and checking my network now and then, it turns out the problem is in fact fixed using the last configuration listed in my question. The last problem I had (and maybe some of the others?) was simply the network genuinely crapping out.

Comment: did you add `bcmwl-kernel-source `. Just run this in terminal `sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source `

Comment: don@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
       [sudo] password for don: 
       Reading package lists... Done
       Building dependency tree       
       Reading state information... Done
       Package bcmwl-kernel-source is not installed, so not removed
       The following packages were automatically installed and are no  longer required:
         dkms patch
       Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
       0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 259 not upgraded.
       don@ubuntu:~$  

do I need to install it?
Is it sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source?

Comment: Ok, I just went ahead and ran `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`
Haven't spent this much time playing solitaire since high school. Had to restart terminal halfway through, but it picked up right where it left off when I restarted the command.

It seems to have been successful, but no change yet. Going to quickly reboot the system and cross my fingers.

Comment: After reboot, internet speed has jumped from nearly nothing to 5.4 Mbps. Not fantastic, but functional.

I'm not sure if this has fixed the issue or not. We'll see if it keeps up.

Comment: remove `b43-fwcutter` &  `firmware-b43-lpphy-installer` .. Either these two or `bcmwl-kernel-source` is required. In fact first two are replacement for later. :(