# How do I get a Broadcom BCM43225 wireless card working?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, broadcom

I updated my 12.04 today and it broke my wireless connection on Acer Aspire 5942G.

```
isa@ubuntu: iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

isa@ubuntu: lspci|grep Network
03:00.0 Network controller:Broadcom Corporation BCM43225 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2):

Plug into ethernet and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -r b43 ssb wl
sudo modprobe wl
```

After a few seconds wireless activated and detected my newtork. (The above commands were run by using wired network of course)

Answer (score 1):

You might try this:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/cfg80211.conf
```

Add one line:

```
options cfg80211 ieee80211_regdom=UK
```

Proofread, save and close gedit. Unload and reload brcmsmac:

```
sudo modprobe -r brcmsmac
sudo modprobe brcmsmac
```

Check:

```
sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep cfg | tail -n20
cat /sys/module/cfg80211/parameters/ieee80211_regdom
```

It may take a reboot.

Source: [Ubuntu Forums: BCM43225 and limitation UK/Europe Channels 12/13](http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=35909)